# Backbone: How do I pass parameters with fetch?

Tags: backbone.js

I have read all the posts on Stackoverflow regarding this issue and tried the following:

1) Adding `$.param({})` wrapper

```
  messages.fetch({
    data: $.param({ limit: 14 }),
  });
```

2)
Setting `traditional` to `true`

```
  messages.fetch({
    data: { limit: 14 },
    traditional: true
  });
```

3)
Setting `processData` to `true`

```
  messages.fetch({
    data: { limit: 14 },
    processData: true,
  });
```

---

Despite this, none of these methods work. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: `Despite this, none of these methods work.` 

So what is happening exactly? You shouldn't need to use `param`, `processData` or `traditional`? 

I assume messages is an instance of `Backbone.Collection`? When you fetch like `messages.fetch({ data: { limit: 14 }})` your request to the server should look something like `api/messages?limit=14`. Can you show the url for that `GET` request?

Comment: You can easily check this if you check the navigation tab of your debugger console.

Answer (score 0):

For what I think you're tying to do, you need to use the "url" property on the model/collection. Fetch is a GET type, not a PUT or POST so you aren't sending "data" to the server. Try something like the following:

Note that **$.param({ limit: 14 })** returns **"limit=14"** The point is, that is not a valid serialized object that the server is going to understand.

If your "*fetch*" method is a "*HttpGet*"

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    // place holder for models api. Also look at: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot
    _baseUrl = 'api/somewhere/great'

    // see: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url
    url: function() {
        // this returns 'api/somewhere/great?limit=14';
        return this._baseUrl + '?' + $.param({ limit: 14 });
    }
});
```

Now, if you want to *HttpPut* or *HttpPost*, then you can override "fetch" and do something like the following:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    url = 'api/somewhere/great'

    fetch: function(options) {
        options = options || {
            data: {
                limit: 14
            }
        };

        /*
            signature method of sync: Backbone.sync = function (method, model, options)
        */
        return this.sync("create", this, options);
    }
});
```

**References:**

- http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/